# How did Kurlbaum and others measure the intensity of each wavelength to get blackbody radiation curve?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, thermal-radiation, radiation, wavelength

In 1900 Plank was faced with data that didn't agree with the Plank-Wien law.  This data that plots different temperature curves - wavelength on the horizontal and intensity on the vertical (or rather energy on the vertical).  These curves show a "freeze out" of certain oscillators.  My question is, with 19th century tech, how did they measure intensity at each wavelength.  How did they detect non visible wavelengths?  Understanding the mechanisms of the experiments will help my understanding overall of the problem of blackbody radiation (which is a measure of three things, heat, intensity/energy, and wavelength).

Comment: Filters, but more likely, spectrometers. They put prisms next to prisms next to prisms. Diffraction gratings are nice too

Comment: This might be better asked at the History of Science and Mathematics stack exchange. In any event, Hershel discovered infrared light in 1800, using a prism and thermometer. Spectrometers/spectroscopes existed at least as far back as 1851.

Comment: As per @naturallyInconsistent they cascaded prisms: Piazzi-Smyth used 10 cascaded carbon disulfide-filled prisms to separate the sodium D lines back before 1900. He tried to thermally shield the very temperature sensitive prisms by covering the cascade with wool blankets. Those folks back then were astoundingly resourceful and relentless.

Comment: I would suggest watching KathyLovesPhysics on YT; she has a wonderful series on the history, that she manually dug up the original papers and correspondences.

Comment: Thank you (everyone) who responded.  I will check out the links